# HAProxy track_script + nopreempt not working

Tags: haproxy, keepalived

I have 2 nodes with Keepalived v1.2.13, in Amazon AWS VPC.

I'm trying to achieve this scenario, assuming Node1 is MASTER:
If I stop HAProxy or stop keepalived or stop the node, failover to Node2.
If I start HAProxy back up on Node1 or start keepalived or start the node, do *not* failover to Node1 (no flapping).

With the following configuration, only by stopping keepalived or stopping the node, does the failover works. The priority change due to the track_script doesn't seem to affect the MASTER election.

Node1

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {       # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
script "killall -0 haproxy"     # cheaper than pidof
interval 2                      # check every 2 seconds
fall 2
weight 2                        # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    advert_int 2
    state BACKUP
    nopreempt
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 101
    unicast_peer {
        172.17.16.10
    }

    notify_master "/etc/keepalived/randomscript.sh"
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

Node2

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {       # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
script "killall -0 haproxy"     # cheaper than pidof
interval 2                      # check every 2 seconds
fall 2
weight 2                        # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    advert_int 2
    state BACKUP
    nopreempt
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    unicast_peer {
        172.17.16.11
    }

    notify_master "/etc/keepalived/randomscript.sh"
    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried on both nodes : state EQUAL, priority 100. This cause a race condition when both instances are booting at the same time, both transition to MASTER, execute the randomscript.sh, and 4-5 seconds after that one node transition to BACKUP, but I don't want the script to be executed.

Comment: migrate your cluster to pacemaker

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using on **both** nodes :

```
state EQUAL
priority 100
```

The race condition was due to some kind of issue with the security group of the instances. So this is an issue specific to ***AWS***.

For an unknown reason, VRRP Unicast works even though not explicitly allowed in the security group. I explicitly opened it (Custom Protocol 112) and it fixed the issue. It seems like it takes time to allow the packet during the initialization of a stack.

Comment: https://github.com/acassen/keepalived/issues/707, as per the community EQUAL is not a state.